# Where is it documented that Option<T> is Drop?

Tags: rust, destructor, traits

I was hoping that if I wrap a `Box<T>` into an `Option`, drop just does its thing. And this program indeed outputs "dropped":

```rust
trait Foo {}

struct Bar {}

impl Foo for Bar {}

impl Drop for Bar {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("dropped")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Box::new( Bar {} ) as Box<Foo>;
    let _y = Option::Some(x);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=25e52859266a238825ca3b6a7f12ff57)

I checked the documentation of both [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) and [`Drop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Drop.html) and I could not find a description of this behavior. Did I miss some compiler magic, or am I right that it cannot be implemented elsewhere, just in the trait declaration or implementor definition?

How does `Option` implement `Drop` and why is it missing from the documentation?

Comment: Asking "where something is documented" — is very close to being closed: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam*.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=6897112ae5fd197a8ca45f4f83ce77ca, ..., ..., ..., it doesn't

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The docs don't mention `Option<T>` implementing `Drop` because it doesn't implement it.

The `Drop` trait is only needed when you want your struct or enum to have some *special* behaviour. If the only thing you need is to free the memory and run child elements' destructors, the compiler will do so on its own. From the relevant page in the [Rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/destructors.html):

> If a struct has no special logic for being dropped other than dropping its children, then it means `Drop` doesn't need to be implemented at all!

`Option` has no `Drop` implementation because there's no special logic involved in its destruction, unlike with `Rc` (which decrements the reference counter), or with a `MutexGuard` (which unlocks the parent mutex). You can observe the same behaviour with your own types, `Bar`s in a `struct Thingie(Bar, Bar)` will be dropped the same as if wrapped in `Some`.

Note that everywhere above "X has no `Drop` implementation" really means no implementation - the compiler will not make one implicitly.

You can also directly test if a type implements `Drop` or not:

```
fn test_for_drop<T: Drop>() { }

fn main() {
    test_for_drop::<Option<i32>>();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1347fbe02bd9dedd4cbbdb0820211a92)

This produces an error:

> ```
> error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::option::Option<i32>: std::ops::Drop` > is not satisfied
>  --> src/main.rs:4:5
>   |
> 4 |     test_for_drop::<Option<i32>>();
>   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::ops::Drop` is not implemented for `std::option::Option<i32>`
>   |
> note: required by `test_for_drop`
>  --> src/main.rs:1:1
>   |
> 1 | fn test_for_drop<T: Drop>() {}
>   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

Comment: Great answer, thank you. So this is pure compiler magic, like I have expected.

Comment: Not sure I'd call it magic. The compiler will still (recursively) call drop when structures containing fields that implement `Drop` go out of scope. A type that doesn't itself implement drop may still have drop calls made when it goes out of scope.

Comment: @DavidBrown I wouldn't personally consider it too magic either, but the whole magic issue is a bit muddy, so I didn't want to comment on it in the answer.